# Ding sound while tabbing in superclassed edit control - winapi - windows7

Tags: winapi

Its been asked before, but what I found was either mfc, or was not for a superclassed control, or maybe my keyword choice was not good(my vocabulary is limited)

I am developing in pure win32 and c++ in Devc++. I have a few Edit controls superclassed where Tab key presses and Return key presses are controled, but whenever I press Tab there is this Ding sound which is very annoying, not sure it is there because I am doing something wrong or what. Anyway, how do I remove it ?

This is my first attempt at superclassing, so if you have any other advice regarding the code, please let me know

Code:

```
    LRESULT APIENTRY EditSuperClassWndProc ( HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
    {

        switch (message)
        {           
               case WM_KEYDOWN:

                      if ( isMyScreen )
                      {
                          if ( (int)wParam == VK_RETURN )
                          {
                              DWORD wparam = MAKELONG( 0, BN_CLICKED );
                              SendMessage( GetParent( hwnd ), WM_COMMAND, (WPARAM)wparam, (LPARAM)hButton );
                          }
                          else if ( (int)wParam == VK_TAB )
                          {
                               HWND nextInLine;

                               if( hwnd == hEditP )
                                   nextInLine = hEditL;
                               else if ( hwnd == hEditL )
                                   nextInLine = hEditP;

                               SendMessage( nextInLine, EM_SETSEL, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)-1 );
                               SetFocus( nextInLine );
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              return CallWindowProc( oldWndProc, hwnd, message, wParam, lParam );
                          }
                      }

                      return CallWindowProc( oldWndProc, hwnd, message, wParam, lParam );
                      break;

               default:

                     return CallWindowProc( oldWndProc, hwnd, message, wParam, lParam );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following code to your switch block:

```
case WM_CHAR:
    if (wParam == VK_TAB)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return CallWindowProc(oldWndProc, hwnd, message, wParam, lParam );
    }
    break;
```

Comment: I tried that (for a different reason) but it doesn't work always eg pressing *control* key and *tab*. The  *wParam* is different from *VK_TAB*! *WM_KEYDOWN* covers every situation